# CRON jobs on LocalHost

Tags: php, cron

Need your help.

I need to run the CRON jobs on my local host as i am fetching feeds using RSS feeder. Please suggest how this can be achieved.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to [this simple manual](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html). This explains you how Cron works and how to add tasks to your crontab.

**EDIT**

Asuming you are on GNU/Linux, edit your crontab:

```
$ crontab -e
```

And add at the end the following line to execute it every minute:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /route/to/your/script.php
```

Make sure that your php executable is in */usr/local/bin*

Comment: Actually i need to run the CRON from my LOCALHOST. Please suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: 'crontab -e' will open the cron list for your username on your host. Assuming this is a Linux question.

Answer (score 1):

If you can try to divide your problem into two, it might be easier to solve for you:
-Writing a script which fetches the rss feed and does whatever you want it to do
-Scheduling the run of that script using a cron job.

These two parts are usually independent of each other.

Are you already done with the first part? Do you have a script which can do the fetching?

If it is ready already. What type of script is it? Perl,python, something else?

**UPDATE:**
So you want to call a PHP script on a schedule using cron jobs.

You'll probably get permission errors in your first tries, so chmod your php script to 0755.

Open up your terminal and try [the code examples here](http://mcapewell.wordpress.com/2006/09/02/calling-php-from-a-cron-job/).

Once you find a working command the first part is complete.

Now with the easy part.
Type crontab -e
Press insert

Let's say within the above examples the "wget http://www.domain.com/file.php" worked for you, then type in:
*/5 * * * * wget http://www.domain.com/file.php

In my terminal, I need to press esc-shift and press z two times to close the crontab. If it works for you too great. You will get one line output saying `crontab installed`. Job done. Every five minutes your php script will work.

Comment: thansk for your reply...

Comment: i am done with the first part. need to Job schedule (CRON) to be done on my local Host. i was using PHP and MySQL. Please suggest how to go about

Answer (score 0):

if you're working on a Windows environment, the easiest way to achieve this would be to set up a scheduled task to execute the PHP script that will fetch your RSS data (using the php executable - see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php))